# why POST request method returns null but GET request returns correct object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

This is my controller code :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetWebsite(int Id)
{
    var website = await _uWebsitesService.GetWebsite(Id);
    return (website == null ? this.Json("Website Not Found") : this.Json(website));
}
```

And this is my ajax :

```
$(".edit-website-btn").on("click", function () {

let id = $(this).attr('data-id');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/userpanel/GetWebsite/",
    data: { Id: id },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    },
  })
})
```

When I check the result in console log, it's null when request type is post but when I change The ajax request and controller method to GET it returns the correct object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because for your post method you are using application/json content that doesnt send id to an action, so action is using id=0 by default and can't get any data. Get action has a correct id and returns data. you can try to fix ajax for post by removing contentType: "application/json"

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/userpanel/GetWebsite/",
    data: { Id: id },
    dataType: "json",
    .....
```

but imho better to use GET

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/userpanel/GetWebsite?id="+id,
   dataType: "json",
    ...
```

and maybe you should try this too

```
 let Id = $(this).data('id');
 //or
 let Id = this.getAttribute('data-id');
```

Comment: I removed content type from ajax request but problem still persist, in Get Method there is no problem but these problem is in Post method

Comment: @Pablo Did you check id in javascript?

Comment: Yes, Id is exist in pay load in both situations ( with content-type and without it )

Comment: @Pablo and check id in the controller action too

Comment: Yes, Id in action is 0, I tried your solution again and it's worked correctly. I think the ajax codes was cached previous time. thank

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` parameter in the ajax call is an object, which just so happens to have a property called `Id` with the value you want.

However, your C# method expects *just* an integer, not an object *with a property* called "Id".

Simply change the JavaScript to only post the integer.

```
data: id,
```

To also help out C#'s binding, you should also specify that the parameter is from the request's body. This is techinally optional, but might help with maintainability and ensuring your value doesn't accidently come in from another source (like a rouge query param).

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetWebsite([FromBody] int Id)
```

If you need to pass more than one value in the POST call, you'll need to make a class in C# and bind that instead of the int.

Comment: I change the data object to your suggestion ( data : id ) but problem not solved, however by adding [frombody] problem solved.

mostly I want to know why this is happening. my other question is why my data object ( 
data : { Id : id } ) is working correctly in Get Method